# Accessing a slot in the results of wilcox_test

Tags: r, slot

I'm doing a test on some data:

```
wilcox_test(y ~ x, distribution="exact", conf.int=TRUE)
#        Exact Wilcoxon Mann-Whitney Rank Sum Test
#
#    data:  y by x (1, 2)
#    Z = 1.8732, p-value = 0.06106
#    alternative hypothesis: true mu is not equal to 0
#    95 percent confidence interval:
#     0 2
#    sample estimates:
#    difference in location 
#                         1
```

The number displayed under `difference in location` is the Hodges-Lehmann estimator. I want to assign it to a variable for further calculation. But I do not know:

### How can I access the value of the "difference in location"?

I looked at `str(wilcox_test(y ~ x, distribution="exact", conf.int=TRUE))`, which gives me:

```
Formal class 'ScalarIndependenceTestConfint' [package "coin"] with 7 slots
  ..@ confint     :function (level)  
  ..@ conf.level  : num 0.95
  ..@ nullvalue   : num 0
  ..@ distribution:Formal class 'ExactNullDistribution' [package "coin"] with 7 slots
  .. .. ..@ q         :function (p)  
  .. .. ..@ d         :function (x)  
  .. .. ..@ support   :function ()  
  .. .. ..@ parameters: list()
  .. .. ..@ pvalue    :function (q)  
  .. .. ..@ p         :function (q)  
  .. .. ..@ name      : chr "exact distribution (via Streitberg-Roehmel algorithm)"
  ..@ statistic   :Formal class 'ScalarIndependenceTestStatistic' [package "coin"] with 14 slots
  .. .. ..@ alternative                : chr "two.sided"
  .. .. ..@ teststatistic              : Named num 1.87
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "1"
  .. .. ..@ standardizedlinearstatistic: Named num 1.87
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "1"
  .. .. ..@ linearstatistic            : num 4246
  .. .. ..@ expectation                : Named num 3875
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "1"
  .. .. ..@ covariance                 :Formal class 'Variance' [package "coin"] with 1 slot
  .. .. .. .. ..@ variance: Named num 39334
  .. .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "1"
  .. .. ..@ xtrans                     : num [1:124, 1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:124] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr "1"
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "assign")= int 1
  .. .. ..@ ytrans                     : num [1:124, 1] 114.5 93.5 9 50 114.5 ...
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "assign")= int 1
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr ""
  .. .. ..@ xtrafo                     :function (data, numeric_trafo = id_trafo, factor_trafo = f_trafo, ordered_trafo = of_trafo, 
    surv_trafo = logrank_trafo, var_trafo = NULL, block = NULL)  
  .. .. ..@ ytrafo                     :function (data)  
  .. .. ..@ x                          :'data.frame':   124 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. .. .. ..$ x: Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. .. ..@ y                          :'data.frame':   124 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. .. .. ..$ y: num [1:124] 7 5 0 2 7 1 0 9 1 7 ...
  .. .. ..@ block                      : Factor w/ 1 level "0": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. .. ..@ weights                    : num [1:124] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..@ estimates   : list()
  ..@ method      : chr "Wilcoxon Mann-Whitney Rank Sum Test"
```

But `wilcox_test(...)@estimates` only returns:

```
list()
```

which appears empty.

So where is the `1` stored that is listed under `difference in location` in the results???

---

Additional explanation:

This works:

```
hle <- wilcox.test(x, y, paired = TRUE, correct = FALSE, conf.int = TRUE)$estimate
```

But that is a different test and not appropriate to my data.

Comment: Try `fit <- wilcox_test(y ~ x, distribution="exact", conf.int=TRUE);
as.numeric(confint(fit)$estimate)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do a little bit of digging to figure this out since the `difference in location` value is nested down a couple of levels, but I'll walk you through it using an example object provided in the help file for `wilcox_test` - the object is named `wt`, and I'll include it below. For things like this, I usually start by inspecting the `show` method of the class of interest -

```
R> class(wt)
[1] "ScalarIndependenceTestConfint"
attr(,"package")
[1] "coin"
R> getMethod("show","ScalarIndependenceTestConfint")
Method Definition:

function (object) 
{
    x <- object
    stat <- x@statistic@teststatistic
    names(stat) <- "Z"
    dist <- x@distribution
    cld <- class(dist)
    attributes(cld) <- NULL
    distname <- switch(cld, AsymptNullDistribution = "Asymptotic", 
        ApproxNullDistribution = "Approximative", ExactNullDistribution = "Exact")
    dataname <- varnames(x@statistic)
    ci <- confint(object, level = object@conf.level)
    RET <- list(statistic = stat, p.value = x@distribution@pvalue(stat), 
        alternative = x@statistic@alternative, method = paste(distname, 
            x@method), data.name = dataname, conf.int = ci$conf.int, 
        estimate = ci$estimate)
    if (length(x@nullvalue)) 
        RET$null.value = c(mu = x@nullvalue)
    if (length(x@estimates)) 
        RET <- c(RET, x@estimates)
    class(RET) <- "htest"
    print(RET)
    invisible(RET)
}
<environment: namespace:coin>
```

The line of interest is the last item in the `RET` list - `estimate = ci$estimate`, which was calculated above as `ci <- confint(object, level = object@conf.level)`. So with the example object, `wt.ci <- confint(wt, level=.95)`, you can do

```
R> wt.ci$estimate
difference in location 
                -0.305
```

which matches

```
R> wt

    Exact Wilcoxon Mann-Whitney Rank Sum Test

data:  pd by age (12-26 Weeks, At term)
Z = -1.2247, p-value = 0.2544
alternative hypothesis: true mu is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.76  0.15
sample estimates:
difference in location 
                -0.305
```

---

From the help file `?wilcox_test()`:

```
water_transfer <- data.frame(
  pd = c(0.80, 0.83, 1.89, 1.04, 
         1.45, 1.38, 1.91, 1.64, 0.73, 1.46,
         1.15, 0.88, 0.90, 0.74, 1.21),
  age = factor(c(rep("At term", 10), rep("12-26 Weeks", 5))))
##
wt <- wilcox_test(pd ~ age, data = water_transfer, 
                  distribution = "exact", conf.int = TRUE)
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you for the explanation. This will help me to deal with similar situations. Great learning :-)